# How can I change my wallpaper daily?

Tags: wallpaper

I am trying to set my android device's background image to change daily. I have been using Google's [Wallpaper](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.wallpaper&hl=en) app but recently have been getting repeats. I am trying to use [unsplash source](https://source.unsplash.com) instead. Is there a way I can do this, without root, using unsplash source?

Answer (score 0):

There's an app called [Casualis](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ph.url.tangodev.randomwallpaper) this app let's you do exactly what you're looking for.

Features:

- Set a random wallpaper every 1/3/6/12 hours or every 1/3/7 days, at the time you prefer;
- Choose a wallpaper manually among over 3000 high-resolution images or use your own images;
- Set a random wallpaper using the widget or with a shake of your smartphone;
- Apply random effects to the wallpapers;
- Customize Casualis by buying extra functionalities.

**I never used the app, but it seems to have some good reviews**